# Fourier series from first principles

Tags: fourier-series

Hello i need help with understanding what is meant by this question

$$s(t)=2+e^{4t} $$

Expand the signal $s(t)$ into both its trigonometric and complex exponential Fourier series from first principles.

i get how to get the Fourier series of $s(t)$ using the normal formulas ($a_0$ an $b_n$ etc) but not from first principles.

Comment: Trigonometric probably means $\sum_k a_k\cos(kt) + b_n\sin(kt), a_n,b_n \in \mathbb{R}$, complex exponential $\sum_k c_k\exp(i k t), c_k \in \mathbb{C}$

Comment: I am also unsure about "first principles". Maybe they mean directly from the definition with no usage of transform tables.

Comment: Welcome to the site by the way. You are encouraged to learn typesetting formulas with MathJax (LaTeX) and show any own efforts done in the question, especially if it seems like a homework question.